# package with memoir-like sidebar functionality for standard book class

Tags: packages, memoir, document-classes, marginnote, sidenotes

Is there a package that provides memoir's sidebar functionality for the standard book class? The key features being better utilizing the margin area (by floating to top: but it would be nice if this were optional), and crossing page boundaries, and if necessary running multiple pages.

Note: `sidenotes` doesn't seem to provide these features unless I missed something.

Comment: Two suggestions, neither of which you might like. 1) extract the `sidebar` functionality from `memoir`'s code, make it in to a package, with appropriate acknowledgements, and submit it to CTAN, or 2) use `memoir` instead of `book` as `memoir` does all that `book` does and more.

Comment: @PeterWilson Actually, I ended up using memoir and make some customizations. I really like it a lot. Nevertheless, if one day someone more versed than I am in programming tex/latex can strip those relevant parts and make it a package, I do think that would be useful to someone.